# the teacher that was substitute

Tags: word-choice

Is there any way that I can use in adjective + noun for the following meaning? 
I want to talk about "**the teacher that was a substitute**" but this way seems to me long, unnatural and wordy.

Can I say for example "substitutable teacher" and the the meaning will still remain?

Context: Jack, a **substitutable teacher**, went on the street and then he noticed to strong voice behind him..."

Another example: "I saw the **substitutable teacher** last week"

Comment: In the U.S., _substitute teacher_ is the term that is used. You're correct in saying that your original wording is "long and unnatural," and your revised version sounds great.

Comment: In the U.S., if it is clear from the context that teachers are being discussed, "sub" is a normal abbreviation for "substitute teacher".  With this meaning, the "sub" abbreviation does not have the period that most abbreviations have.  "Sub" is less formal than "substitute teacher".  Some people think that the term "sub" is also less respectful than the term "substitute teacher".

Comment: [Substitute teacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_teacher) is correct, but **supply teacher** is also common.

Comment: The original teacher was **substitutable** with the **substitute** teacher.

Comment: @dinerdash - **supply teacher** looks like a UK usage.  Americans would generally not understand what you meant by that.

Comment: @stangdon - it is a UK usage, but as the Wikipedia article notes, it is also what we called substitute teachers in Ontario, where I went to school. I doubt Americans would have trouble with the meaning.

Comment: @dinerdash - Perhaps, but in about 35 years of speaking US English and reading primarily US English texts, I have never, ever, not once run across the term *supply teacher*, hence my feeling that most Americans would not understand what you meant by it.  All I'm saying is that this should remind us to be careful about assuming what will be understood or not in a given place.

Comment: @stangdon - I agree, but nowhere in the original question is it stated that the poster is seeking a specifically American English answer. That appears to be your own assumption.

Comment: @dinerdash - True, but he does specifically use the word "substitute", and other commenters began their comments with "In the US..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although substitutable is an adjective, we don't hear people say substitutable teacher.

The noun substitute usually functions as an adjective. So you should say:

I saw the substitute (or sub in informal English) teacher last week.

Answer (score 3):

The suffix -able is usually added to verbs to form adjectives meaning:

> *-able* also  *-ible* [in adjectives]
>
> that you can do something to:
>
> washable (=it can be washed)
>
> unbreakable (=it cannot be broken)
>
> loveable (=easy to love)

from: [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/-able)

Hence, a *substitutable teacher* would stand for a teacher who could be replaced by a substitute, not the substitute themselves.

Your construction might be a bit wordy, as suggested in comments (although it is clear and understandable) and you can replace it with *substitute teacher* (also suggested in comments)